# android AR core throws Device not supported on emulator

Tags: android, arcore

I followed the google [instructions](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator) for setting up AR core on the emulator. I installed the tools and also installed the latest Google play services for AR on the emulator.

I call this function in OnResume() in the activity:

```java
switch (ArCoreApk.getInstance().requestInstall(boundActivity, mUserRequestedInstall)) {
      case INSTALLED:
           session = new Session(boundActivity);
           break;
      case INSTALL_REQUESTED:
           mUserRequestedInstall = false;
           break;
}
```

When the app receives the INSTALLED response, creating the session throws:
com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableDeviceNotCompatibleException, before this there are some error lines:

E/native: session_create_implementation_shared.cc:2051 Unable to obtain device profile from the content provider: NOT_FOUND: Device is not supported.

E/native: session_create_implementation_shared.cc:2395 Failed to create calibration config and device profile.

The device API is 30 and I am using a x86 ABI with android 11.

Comment: Did you find any solution for the issue?

Comment: I used API level 29. And use the latest AR core apk from the github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use API level 29 (android Q instead of R)

Comment: I'm facing the similar issue with actual Android device. It works if Android API level is 29 but does show the Google Play Service for AR Core dialog if API level is 30. Any solution?

Comment: Found any solution yet?

Comment: @JaswantSingh the solution that worked for me was to use API level 29 instead of 30, but this was quite some time ago

Comment: Found the solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68365368/arcoreapk-check-availability-not-working-on-api-30/68365747#68365747