# ArCoreApk check availability not working on api 30

Tags: android, arcore

ArCoreApk check availability returns true on API Level 29 and below but false on 30. Any ideas?

```
fun checkArCoreAvailability(context: Context) {
    var message: String? = null
    var isArCoreInstalled = false
    try {
        when (ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(context)) {
            ArCoreApk.Availability.UNKNOWN_ERROR -> {
                message = "This device does not support AR, starting normal session"
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.UNKNOWN_CHECKING -> {
                message = "This device does not support AR, starting normal session"
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    checkArCoreAvailability(context)
                }, 250)
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.UNKNOWN_TIMED_OUT -> {
                message = "This device does not support AR, starting normal session"
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.UNSUPPORTED_DEVICE_NOT_CAPABLE -> {
                message = "This device does not support AR, starting normal session"
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.SUPPORTED_NOT_INSTALLED -> {
                message = "Please install ArCore to use pinned annotations"
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.SUPPORTED_APK_TOO_OLD -> {
                message = "Please update ArCore to use pinned annotations"
            }
            ArCoreApk.Availability.SUPPORTED_INSTALLED -> {
                isArCoreInstalled = true
                message = "Starting AR Session"
            }
            null -> {
                message = "This device does not support AR, starting normal session"
            }
        }
    } catch (e: UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException) {
        message = "Please install ARCore to use pinned annotations"
    } catch (e: UnavailableUserDeclinedInstallationException) {
        message = "Please install ARCore to use pinned annotations"
    } catch (e: UnavailableApkTooOldException) {
        message = "Please update ARCore to use pinned annotations"
    } catch (e: UnavailableSdkTooOldException) {
        message = "Please update this app"
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        message = "This device does not support AR, starting normal session"
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add appropriate query item to your manifest:

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.ar.core" />
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Works! Had no idea about queries. Introduced in API Level 30.